# Lagrange identity in integral form

Tags: inequality

I can prove Lagrange identity in discrete form, but I couldn't find any similarity to apply it for integral case. Here is what I mean,
$$
\Bigg(\int_a^bx(t)y(t)dt\Bigg)^2=\int_a^bx^2(t)dt\int_a^by^2(t)dt-\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b\int_a^b[x(s)y(t)-y(s)x(t)]^2dsdt
$$
Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Fubini-Tonelli theorem, you can write the RHS in the following form:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}x^2(s)y^2(t)ds\, dt+\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}x^2(t)y^2(s)ds\,dt-\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}\left(x(s)y(t)-x(t)y(s)\right)^2 ds\, dt = \int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}x(t)y(t)x(s)y(s) dt\,ds, $$
but this is clearly equal to $\left(\int_{a}^{b}x(t)y(t) dt\right)^2.$